# Collapse accordions except current, by removing class of each, but this.parent?

Tags: jquery, accordion

So I'm stuck with a plugin that offers a simple accordion, but doesn't offer auto-collapse. I was trying to create a simple script, but I'm not succeeding.

Let me offer some DOM structure:

```
.mx-groupbox-collapsible.collapsed
  .mx-groupbox-header
  .content
.mx-groupbox-collapsible.collapsed
  .mx-groupbox-header
  .content
.mx-groupbox-collapsible.collapsed
  .mx-groupbox-header
  .content
```

Assuming the structure speaks for itself, but one thing: when the `.collapsed` class is removed, it'll expand the item (*in my opinion the opposite way of building an accordion..*).

Somehow the only way to fire the jQuery script is to target the header ( `$('.mx-groupbox-header').click()`). What it should do is find each item that does not have a `.collapsed` class and add it, while removing it from it's parent.

My best guess was this piece of jQuery.

```
// Target the inner accordion item header
$(".mx-groupbox-header").click(function() { 

  // Target each accordion item that doesn't have class 'collapsed',
  // except the parent of the current clicked item
  $('.mx-groupbox-collapsible').not([$('.collapsed'),$(this).parent()]).each(function(){

      // Add 'collapsed' class, so current opened item, except current will collapse
      $(this).addClass('collapsed');
  });
});
```

Who can tell me where I'm going wrong and offer me the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's totally inversed than it's usually done...

If that's really your markup you're going to use (click on header and stuff),
you should, on header click - find the `.closest()` (groupbox parent) like:

```js
// Cache dropdowns
var $collapsible = $('.mx-groupbox-collapsible');


// Target the inner accordion item header
$(".mx-groupbox-header").click(function() { 

  // Find header's collapsible parent
  var $myCollapsible = $(this).closest('.mx-groupbox-collapsible');

  // Target each accordion item that doesn't have class 'collapsed',
  // except the parent of the current clicked item
  $collapsible.not( $myCollapsible ).addClass("collapsed");

  // Eventually (if needed?) do also:
  $myCollapsible.removeClass("collapsed");
});
```

Comment: Thanks Roko, that immediately fixed my issue! It seems creating a variable of 'this.parent' with the 'closest()' did the trick. Nice one! Sadly enough, I'm stuck with this markup, as it's part of a native 'widget' with the Mendix framework that I have to use. As I can't write markup myself, I was already happy I could add some jQuery functionalities.. Nevertheless, big thanks Roko!

Comment: You're welcome. Really glad it helped & thanks for the reward! @SanderSchaeffer